# Create a new Formula field. return Field value if Field length for First Name or Last Name = 3 or more characters

Tags: salesforce1-app

I need a formula field for my reporting where if Field value length for First Name or Last Name = 3 or more characters.

I tied this so far

IF (ISBLANK(Firstname)0,1 
IF (ISBLANK(Lastname) 0,1
IF(ISBLANK(Email) 0,1

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking because the formula you've tried so far doesn't make much sense. Is the desired result to display the `Email` if the first name or last name is greater than 2 characters?

Comment: I am trying to use formual field as a filter on a report. Wants to display results  where Field value length for First Name or Last Name is equal to  3 or more characters on Contact.

Comment: Wouldn't `LEN(FirstName) > 2 || LEN(LastName) > 2` be enough on a checkbox formula?

Comment: @DrewKennedy. Yes it worked. thanks for the help .

Answer (score 1):

Formula field with return type of "Checkbox":

```
OR( LEN(FirstName) > 2, LEN(LastName) > 2 )
```